# Adding data to a pivot table while inserting a new record using select option Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So here's the problem:

I created a CRUD system so an administrator can create/read/update/delete users.
The problem is that I can't select a role for a user in my CRUD system. Any help would really be appreciated!

I will point out the 3 migrations I am using: users, roles and the pivot table for them user_role.

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
    });

Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('name', 40);
        $table->string('description', 255);
    });

Schema::create('user_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('role_id');
    });
```

This is in my User model:

```
public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'user_role', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}
```

And this is in my Role model:

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_role', 'role_id', 'user_id');
}
```

I seed some roles in RoleTableSeeder like this:

```
Role::create([
        'id'            => 1,
        'name'          => 'Admin',
        'description'   => 'Admin User.'
    ]);
    Role::create([
        'id'            => 2,
        'name'          => 'Vendor',
        'description'   => 'Vendor User.'
    ]);
    Role::create([
        'id'            => 3,
        'name'          => 'User',
        'description'   => 'Simple User.'
    ]);
```

This is the code to create a user:

```
        {!! Form::open(['route' => 'admin.users.allusers']) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('Username', 'Username:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('username',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('E-mail', 'E-mail:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('email',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('Role', 'Role:') !!}
            <select class="form-control" id="role" name="role">
                <option value="Administrator">Administrator</option>
                <option value="Vendor">Vendor</option>
                <option value="User" selected="selected">User</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::submit('Create', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
            <a href="{{ route('admin.users.allusers')}}" class="btn btn-primary">Back</a>
        </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Why is role-user relation a many-to-many? It seems you only allow users to have one role assigned in the row. Could you post your controller code that handles the form?

Comment: The role_user is a many-to-many relation because I thought that there can be many users with the same role and vice-verca.

Comment: `public function store(Request $request){ 
        $user=Request::all();
        User::create($user);
        return redirect()->back();
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you create a user, you need to explicitly initialise the **roles** relation.

```
$user = User::create(Request::all()); //user needs to be saved first so that ID is known
$role = Role::whereName(Request::input('role'))->first();
$user->roles()->attach($role);
```

Comment: Does it need something else? I tried that on my controller I shown you before and now I got:

NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 103:
No query results for model [App\Role].

ModelNotFoundException in Builder.php line 209:
No query results for model [App\Role].

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice you use role names in the select dropdown, not IDs. I've updated the answer. There might be another mistake in your app: In the select you use role with value "Administrator", but the name in the database is "Admin"

Comment: Now it seems that it has this problem: 
FatalErrorException in AdminUserController.php line 31:
Call to a member function roles() on array

Line 31: $user->roles()->attach($role);

Comment: Have you done any changes to the code? $user variable is supposed to store the created User object. I've updated the first line. If the problem still occurs, could you do dd($user) and tell me what you see?

Comment: Well I edited the 2nd line as you did too. I also changed the value at the dropdown from Administrator to Admin, to match my database.
I did dd($user). This is what I got:
`array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "M00hwGo1ZJPPFzdmOVtE4PVpfyPJQb6D3RLz6g4g"
  "username" => "asdf"
  "email" => "asdf"
  "role" => "User"
]`

Comment: Could you paste the exact code from your from your controller? You seem to lose $user object somewhere in the process and what you have in $user variable is the values from Request::all(). Make sure you assign whatever you get from User::create() to $user variable

Comment: Yeap! It seems that I forgot to assign User::create() to $user variable. Now it works just fine. I also fixed it for the update section of the CRUD system.
Now one final question that I have. Instead of the CRUD, now in the normal way of creating a user, how can I fix it so anyone that goes to create a new user, by default its attaching a User Role?

Comment: What is the "normal way of creating a user"? :)

Comment: Hehe, I meant when a guest goes to the sign up area and tries to create an account!

Comment: Just fetch the default role from the database like above, but use its name instead of what comes in the request

Comment: Yeap I fixed it. After I save the new user I added this: 
$user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'User')->first());
So when a new user is being created, by default he gets the "User" role. 

Thanks mate for all the help, you' re the best!